# Why can any closed manifold be constructed a fundamental class of coefficient $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, poincare-duality

I am reading now a Milnor and Stasheff's "Characteristic Classes".
In the page 274, there is a sentence "The case $\Lambda= \mathbb{Z/2}$ is particularly important, since the mod 2 homology class

$\mu_{K} \in H_{n}(M, M\setminus K;\mathbb{Z/2}) $

can be constructed directly for an arbitrary manifold, without making any assumption of orientability." which I cannot understand.
Are all manifolds $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ orientable? And if it's true, why?

Comment: Yes, all manifolds are orientable over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, all manifolds are $\mathbb{Z}_2$-orientable. The point is that over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ there's locally only one orientation since $1 = -1$ so there are no global obstructions to gluing local orientations.

Comment: See for instance Hatcher’s “Algebraic topology”, or any other textbook covering Poincare duality.

Comment: Thanks for your advices.Now I can understand the meaning of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ orientation. I simply forget the notion of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.